# Второй xml не создается

Tags: java, android, xml

Для общения с серваком, нужно отправлять ему несколько xml - так прописано в документации, и вот тут возникли сложности, так как второй xml не создается.

Пробовал:

1. Новый экземпляр XmlSerializer и StringWriter с другими именами- создается без ошибок, но всегда пуст, чтобы я туда не записывал.

   При этом Я получаю предупреждение:

   > Variable `xmlcreate1` initializer `Xml.newSerializer()` is redundant less...
   >   Inspection info: This inspection points out the cases where a variable value is never used after its assignment, i.e.:  - the variable never gets read after assignment OR  - the value is always overwritten with another assignment before the next variable read OR  - the variable initializer is redundant (for one of the above two reasons)
2. Поставить null и выдать новый Xml.newSerializer() старому классу- Получаю тот же эффект что и при первом пункте (пустой xml)
3. выдать новый Xml.newSerializer() старому классу- Получаю тот же эффект что и при первом пункте (пустой xml)
4. Просто StartDocument - никакой реакции, просто не перезаписывает старый.

p.s сервер прекрасно реагирует на первый xml и высылает правильный ответ, который мы успешно парсим

Вот что для первого xml:

```
XmlSerializer xmlcreate = Xml.newSerializer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
xmlcreate.setOutput(writer);
xmlcreate.startDocument("UTF-8", true);

xmlcreate.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
xmlcreate.startTag("", "Command");

xmlcreate.startTag("","Type");
xmlcreate.text("SERVER_CONNECTION");
xmlcreate.endTag("","Type");
xmlcreate.endTag("", "Command");
xmlcreate.endDocument();

//Отправляем на сервер xml
DataOutputStream serverOutput = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

serverOutput.writeUTF(writer.toString());

serverOutput.flush();
```

Вот что для второго xml:

```
//xmlcreate=null;

//xmlcreate = Xml.newSerializer();
//writer = new StringWriter();

//xmlcreate.setOutput(writer);

xmlcreate.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
                    xmlcreate.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
//Open Tag <Command>
xmlcreate.startTag("", "Command");

xmlcreate.startTag("","Type");

xmlcreate.text("SERVER_GET_SYSTEMTIME");

xmlcreate.endTag("","Type");
xmlcreate.endTag("", "Command");

serverOutput.writeUTF(writer.toString());

serverOutput.flush();
```

Ничего особого)

Comment: Наверное, для каждого из 4 вариантов нужно привести код

Comment: Да, показывайте код, ибо неясно что вы делаете. В первом варианте предупреждение говорит, что вы не используете созданный экземпляр - либо дальше по коду присваиваете ссылке другое значение. либо больше к ней не обращаетесь (в переводе на русский). В остальных, видимо, подобная ситуация.

Comment: добавил код , воть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удачные намеки на код: 
Вначале должно быть так:

```
writer = new StringWriter();

xmlcreate.setOutput(writer);
```

А также пропустил закрытие:

```
xmlcreate.endDocument();
```